# Sqlite python - attempt to write a read only database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a simple python script that puts data in a database. Both the script and
the database have owner `www-data`. When I run `sudo python` and write the
commands one by one it works, but if I run `python monitor.py` or `sudo python monitor.py` it doesn't work; it says, `"attempt to write a read only database"`.

This is [my script](https://github.com/alexonaci/hackaton/blob/master/monitor.py): (it receives data from arduino)

```
from serial import Serial
from time import sleep
import sqlite3

serial_port = '/dev/ttyACM0';
serial_bauds = 9600;

# store the temperature in the database
def log_light(value):

    conn=sqlite3.connect('/var/db/arduino.db')
    curs=conn.cursor()

    curs.execute("UPDATE sensor1 set status = (?)", (value,))

    # commit the changes
    conn.commit()

    conn.close()

def main():
    s = Serial(serial_port, serial_bauds);
    s.write('T');
    sleep(0.05);
    line = s.readline();
    temperature = line;
    s.write('H');
    sleep(0.05);
    line = s.readline();
    humidity = line;
    s.write('L');
    sleep(0.05);
    line = s.readline();
    light = line;
    log_light(light);

    if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permission problem. Write access is granted only to the user, which is root. You need to change the user to be directly yourself, not root. You can do this using `chmod` on many *nix systems.
You could also gove write access to anyone in the group.

Comment: I need to keep the user www-data so that nginx can access the database.

Comment: @CCezar `chown www-data:www-data /var/db/arduino.db` to change the owner and group of the database to `www-data`.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 728 Mar 26 18:18 monitor.py

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 2048 Mar 26 18:10 arduino.db

Comment: Give write permission to everyone to see if this works.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: chmod 777 www-data

Comment: @DevShark Don't do that, that's horrible for security... Make sure that `www-data` has permissions to the folder that the database is in.

Comment: That was just a temporary measure to see if that was the problem.